# Cleaning a mouse pad

Tags: mouse

I have a pretty expensive mouse pad, it's a SteelSeries surface [QCK+](http://steelseries.com/products/surfaces/steelseries-qck-plus). It's made of some cloth on the top and has a rubber base and it's 450x450mm in size.
Over time (I have it for about a year) it became dusty and a bit greasy.

How should I clean it? Can I just wash it as I do with some clothes? Of course, not in a washing-machine, but in warm water with some cleaning stuff like [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28cleaning_product%29)

I understand that this question is a bit off-topic to SuperUser, but who can know it better? :)

Comment: If this gets closed without being answered, you could always ask in chat, as the question requirements don't apply there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Frequently Asked Questions - How do I clean my HD series mousepad if it gets dirty?](http://faq.steelseries.com/questions/66/How+do+I+clean+my+HD+series+mousepad+if+it+gets+dirty%3F):

> If you are a typical gamer, dirtying your mousepad is something that will inadvertently happen over time. To clean your 9HD mousepad, take a damp cloth and gently wipe the surface. Please do not use chemical cleaners as this may damage and discolor the surface print over time. Using some gentle hand soap on the cloth is okay.

The 9HD and QCK+ look fairly similar, so that should apply to your mousepad as well.

If you're not convinced, I'd recommend contacting the [SteelSeries support](http://steelseries.zendesk.com/). That way, you have somebody to yell at if your mousepad gets damaged.